# I am unable to get the output for the code below

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to get the data for my chart from data.csv file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>D3 test</title>
      <style>

   .grid .tick {
   stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  .grid path {
stroke-width: 0;
   }
.chart {
 }
.main text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
.axis line, .axis path {
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
  }
 circle {
 fill: steelblue;
   }



      </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js">   

                </script>
       <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
      </head>
  <body>
  <div class='content'>
    <!-- /the chart goes here -->
       </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scatterchart.js"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

And the code for scatterchart.js

```
         var data = []
        d3.csv("data.csv", function(csvData) {

         data = csvData.forEach(function(d) { return [ +d.first, +d.second ] });
          console.log(data);

           var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#b41f2d", "#ff7f0e"]);


       var margin = {
        top: 20,
       right: 15,
       bottom: 60,
       left: 25
        }, width = 950 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d[0];
        })])
       .range([0, width]);

       var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d[1];
        })])
      //.range([height, 0]) //flip y
     .range([0, height]);

  var chart = d3.select('body')
   .append('svg:svg')
   .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
   .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .attr('class', 'chart');

  var main = chart.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('class', 'main');

     // draw the x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
     //.orient('bottom')
     .orient('top'); // adjust ticks to new x axis position

      main.append('g')
     //.attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)') // move x axis up
       .attr('class', 'main axis date')
     .call(xAxis);

       // draw the y axis
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(y)
       .orient('left');

       main.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
      .attr('class', 'main axis date')
      .call(yAxis);

      var g = main.append("svg:g");

       g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
         return x(d[0]);
           }) 
         .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return y(d[1]);
       }) 
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d[0]);}) ;

  // begin of drawing lines
         var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d){return x(d[0]);})
     .y(function(d){return y(d[1]);})
      .interpolate("linear");  

        g.append("path")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(data)})
       .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("fill", "none");
     // end of drawing lines

        main.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .call(make_x_axis()
       .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
       .tickFormat(""))

       main.append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(make_y_axis()
      .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
       .tickFormat(""))

       function make_x_axis() {
       return d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
     .ticks(30)
       }

      function make_y_axis() {
     return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
     .orient("left")
       .ticks(17)
     }
     });
```

And data.csv is

```
 first,second
  2,2
  3,3
  4,4
  5,4
  5.5,5
  6,6
  6,7
  6.5,8
  6.5,16
  17,16
```

The error that I'm getting in console window is
[undefined scatterchart.js:6]
[TypeError: n is undefined d3.v3.min.js:3]

How to get the output ?

Comment: You are using two d3.js files simultaneously. Remove one of them and try again.

Comment: removed these tags <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js">                   </script> ,  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script> same result

Comment: what error its showing?

Comment: [undefined scatterchart.js:6]   [TypeError: n is undefined d3.v3.min.js:3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the forEach loop.  I'm not entirely sure you're using it the correct way.  Try this out:

```
csvData.forEach(function (d,i) {
    data[i] = {
      first: +d.first, 
      second: +d.second
    } 
});
```

What this is doing is creating an array of objects whereas in your code you were trying to return an array of arrays with 2 elements.

You can also change d[0] and d[1] to d.first and d.second if you want it's really a preference thing.  I think the dot notation makes things clearer but there are times when you need to use bracket notation.

Also, you'll have to ensure that you're using data everywhere and not csvData as there's a mixture in your code.

You can find a working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/9761412).

Comment: TypeError: n is undefined d3.v3.min.js:3

Comment: Worked fine when I implemented it, check the link to the bl.ock out in the edit to the answer.  Did you check that data/csvData was consistent throughout?

Comment: user1614080 - But why is the color of the bubble(data-point) not changing ? we have this line in code var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#b41f2d", "#ff7f0e"]);

Comment: You haven't specified a domain for the scale, so d3 doesn't know what to do with the values that you pass to it, unless they match the index of your colour vector.  I suspect that you wanted to do is colour the points based on the values.  To do that have a look at [rangeBands](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeBands).  Cause I'm a bit lazy I've just updated fill function to `return color(i)` so that the colour is based on the index. I've updated the [Bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/9761412) with this.

Comment: Thanks user1614080. I was actually looking for the same plot as your updated Bl.ock. But whenever I change the data value in data.csv there comes a default datapoint at [0,0]. How to avoid this ?

Comment: How can I add this code within index.html : var py;
data.map(
    function(d) {
        if (d[1] < py)
            d[1] = py + 1;
        py = d[1];
    }
); that is to plot graph in such a way if Ypresent < Yprevious then the datapoint should be at Yprevious+1.